# Send bean between jsps

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans

I show a list of demandes on my jsp1 and when I choose one I wanna go to jsp2 show the demand details and allow people to comment below.
I'm having this problem, when I send the selected demande and go to jsp2 I find this error : `Cannot find bean: "demand" in scope: "request"`
Here's my code:

JSP1:

```
    <logic:iterate id="demande" name="demandes">
    <html:link  page ="/PAGES/commentaire.jsp" paramId="demand" 
                      paramName="demande" paramProperty="content">
    <bean:write name="demande" property="content" /><br>
    </html:link>
    </logic:iterate>
```

JSP2:

```
<bean:write name="demand"  scope="request"/>
```

I really dont know where the problem might come from, cuz every thing seems pretty right.
Does anyone have an idea.

Seconde version:
JSP1:

```
<html:link  page ="/show.do" paramId="demande" paramName="demande" >
            <bean:write name="demande" property="demandeId" /><br>
        </html:link>
```

struts-config.xml:

```
<action path="/show" 
                type="action.ActionAfficherDemande"             
                validate="true"
                input="/PAGES/JSP1.jsp"
                scope="session">
            <forward name="success" path="/PAGES/JSP2.jsp" redirect="true"/>            
 </action>
```

ActionAfficherDemande.java :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Demande myDemande = (Demande) session.getAttribute("demande");
```

Comment: One more thing, I can see the information, that I've sent, in the URL!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Struts. Struts is an MVC framework. The very simple rule of MVC is: all requests go to a controller, which prepares the model, and then forwards to a view. You should NEVER have a link to a JSP. Always to a controller. All your links should end with `.do`. Never with `.jsp`.

Also, you're confusing request parameters with request attributes. Request parameters are Strings that are sent by the browser to the server using a form, or a link with a query string (`/foo.do?bar=baz` for example). Request attributes are objects that are stored in the request by some component on the server, using `request.setAttribute()`. Your code expects to get the value of a parameter by getting the value of an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting introduction, it explains lots of things.
However, for the first part, I created a controller but I get the same problem, when I do: 
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Demande myDemande = (Demande) session.getAttribute("demande");

It returns null!!
May be I still have problem with the second part of ur answer, that's why I'm getting this error.

Comment: What is sent is a parameter. You get a parameter using request.getParameter(). Not using session.getAttribute(). Read a tutorial about servlets: you don't understand basic concepts of it.

Comment: You are so right, I'll do read some of the concepts.
I still have this problem with request.getParameter() seems like it returns only string!!

Comment: Ok thanks JB Nizet ;)
I found it, the answer in the second part of ur response: the difference between the request attribute and request parameter